# Why does the pipe write end accepts one byte and after that fails with error EBADF?

Tags: c, pipe

I have a problem with my program, which is using IPC message queue. Althought IPC works fine, there is an issue with pipe, which I wasn't able to resolve yet. This is the code of subprocess of my program. It reads one byte from a file and then is supposed to write it to a pipe.

```
char buf;
  int r;
  r = read(fileR, &buf, 1);
  if(r == 0){//file is empty
   cout<<"Empty"<<endl;
   lseek(fileR, 0, SEEK_SET);
   msgbuf.mtype = subProcessCount+1;
   msgbuf.mtext[0] = whichPid;
   sendAndCheck(queue, 3);
  }else{
   //cout<<whichPid<<" writing "<<buf<<" to pipe"<<endl;
   cout<<"Closing pipe[0]"<<endl;
   close(comPipe[0]);
   if(write(comPipe[1], &buf, 1) == -1){
    switch(errno){
     case EACCES: cout<<"EACCESS"; break;
     case EIDRM: cout<<"EIDRM"; break;
     case ENOENT: cout<<"ENOENT"; break;
     case ENOMEM: cout<<"ENOMEM"; break;
     case ENOSPC: cout<<"ENOSPC"; break;
     case EFAULT: cout<<"EFAULT"; break;
     case EINTR: cout<<"EINTR"; break;
     case EINVAL: cout<<"EINVAL"; break;
     case EPIPE: cout<<"EPIPE"; break;
     case EAGAIN: cout<<"EAGAIN"; break;
     case EBADF: cout<<"EBADF"; break;
     case EFBIG: cout<<"EFBIG"; break;
     case EIO: cout<<"EIO"; break;
     default: cout<<"writefail"<<endl; break;
    }
   }else{
    cout<<"written";
   }
   close(comPipe[1]);
   cout<<"Closing pipe[1]"<<endl;
  }
```

This is the code of the parent process, which should read from this pipe when the child process finishes (and then write it to fifo, but now it's not important).

```
 close(comPipe[1]);   
 cout<<"Closing pipe[1]"<<endl;
 outfifo = open(pathBuf.mtext, O_WRONLY );
while(1){
r = read(comPipe[0], &buffer, BUF_SIZE);
cout<<"Buffer size: "<<r<<endl;
write(outfifo, &buffer, r);
if(r < BUF_SIZE){
  break;
 }
}
close(comPipe[0]);
cout<<"Closing pipe[0]"<<endl;
close(outfifo);
```

When I test it, first byte goes into the pipe, but every next byte makes write() return -1 and set error to EBADF.

Have you got a clue about what is going on there? Thanks in advance,
Nebril

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closing the pipe after one write. As I understand it there is no getting it back once it is closed. Subsequent writes to that file descriptor (which I don't actually see anywhere in your code) will set the error "bad file" because the pipe no longer exists.

Comment: If a new file has been assigned that descriptor number, you will end up writing to the wrong file. This can lead to nasty data corruption problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely here:

```
r = read(comPipe[0], &buffer, BUF_SIZE);
cout<<"Buffer size: "<<r<<endl;  
write(outfifo, &buffer, r);
if(r < BUF_SIZE){
```

You are exiting your loop when `r < BUF_SIZE`, but after you read one byte, `r == 1`. Instead, try:

```
written = write(outfifo, &buffer, r);
if (written < r) {
```

That will break and exit when your server can no longer write to `outfifo`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to close the pipe after writing one byte.  I don't see any looping.

Your reader looks a little odd also.

Comment: This code is invoked many times when the program is running, sorry, I should have pointed it out.

Answer (score 0):

I started beeing desperate and I did some random things. One actually worked! I threw every `close(comPipe[1]);` call away and now it's alive! Thanks for help guys :). Still no idea why did it behave like that, but maybe it will help someone... sometime :D